# Add a form of another module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a module called `main` which is my default module and a module called `song`.

I want to put into my `main` module an "add form" of my `song` module.

I don't know if I have to use component, how and where to process the form.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Are you sure your question is for Symfony2?

Comment: No, did not see the tag. I work with Symfony 1.4. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation? Specially [this part of the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms)?

It covers the form system by using a basic contact form:

- You have the controller (the `actions.class.php` inside your `main` module) which create an instance of the form and handle the submission (validation, save, etc ..)
- Then the template (`contactSuccess.php`), which display the form

The main difference is that you probably have a model called Song, so you will have to use the SongForm instead of creating a new one (using `new sfForm()`). For this part, you can see, on the same documentation page, the part [Forms Based on a Model](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_forms_based_on_a_model) which cover the case of an article model.

**Edit:**

A step by step:

In your `main/actions/actions.class.php`:

```
public function executeIndex($request)
{
  $this->form = new SongForm();
  if ($request->isMethod('post'))
  {
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('song'));
    if ($this->form->isValid())
    {
      $song = $this->form->save();

      $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'Thank you, the song has been added');

      $this->redirect('main/index');
    }
  }
}
```

In your template, `main/templates/indexSuccess.php`:

```
<?php if ($sf_user->hasFlash('notice')): ?>
  <div class="flash_notice"><?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('notice') ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php echo $form->renderFormTag('main/index') ?>
  <table>
    <?php echo $form ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And you're done.

I **really** encourage you to read the whole [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/). You will learn lots of things. Basically every thing I described here, is in this tutorial.

For the `sf_guard_user` field, you should redefine it as hidden, and then set a default value with the current connected user.

Create a new form: `/lib/form/CustomSongForm.class.php`

```
<?php

class CustomSongForm extends SongForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();

    $this->widgetSchema['sf_guard_user_ud'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
  }
}
```

Then you can define the default, like you said:

```
}$this->form->setDefault('sf_guard_user_id', $this->getUser()->getId());
```

Comment: First of all, I really thank you.

If I'm well understanding :

In my action.class.php of my MAIN module, I create my form :
    $this->song_form = new SongForm();

In my indexSuccess.php of my MAIN module, I display the form.
    Renders, etc..

But, how can I process my form when tue user submit it ? Because I send the form in the same page (action="")
Moreover, I want a "tankyou" action which displays "Thank you, the song has been added"

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll test it very soon. I have a question, you call the action executeAddSong but the form will be displayed in my indexSuccess.php of my main module. That's the reeson why I tought I could do it in executeIndex and set my form's action like this : action="". Am I wrong ?

Comment: Almost, I've update my answer. You also should change the template name.

Comment: Thank you very much. **Main** is not a good name for a homepage ?

Comment: What do you mean? I usually use the `main` as the default one, which is, defacto, the homepage. By the way, do not forget to accept the answer if it helps you ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I tought you were talking about my main module name ;)
Sure, I test it tonight and I set it as Resolved.
Merci.

Comment: Good evening, everything work very well but the user_id is not saved in my base. Sry, didn't tell you my Song model is linked to sf_guard_user. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a drop down list with a list of sf_guard_user inside? Or do you want to use the logged in user instead?

Comment: No, I unset the sf_guard_user in my form, I want to use the id of the connected user. I found many responses, but they need to have a hidden file in form and I don't think it's the best solution. I was thinking about something like $this->form->setDefault('sf_guard_user_id', $this->getUser()->getId()

Comment: Is that the best practice ? My Song model is related to SfGuardUser, so why do I need to create a custom form ? I could put $this->widgetSchema['sf_guard_user_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(); directly in my Song form configure ?

Comment: Of course you can. But this way, you will **always** have an hidden field for `sf_guard_user`. For example, if you build an admin to manage song, you won't be able to change the `sf_guard_user` from a song because the field will be hidden. You see the difference?